# How to have unique name only inside its has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have `guides` and `categories`. a guide `has_many` categories and `category` belongs to guide.

I want categories to have unique names but only inside the guide they are associated to. e.g. a category with the name 'cat1' can exist twice in the categories db but only if their category belongs to different guides

currently I have in the category model:

```
 validate :name, :uniquenes => true
```

But this is for all names in the category db to be unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to specify the scope of uniqueness:

```
 validate :name, uniqueness: { scope: :guide_id }
```